# Exercise 2.27 in Huybrecht's "Fourier-Mukai transforms"

Tags: derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I have some questions about *Exercise 2.27* from
Huybrecht's script "Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry":

> **Exercise 2.27**: Suppose $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \to C 
> \to 0$ is a
> short exact sequence in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$.
> Show that under the full embedding $ \mathcal{A} 
> \hookrightarrow K(\mathcal{A})$  (or
> $\mathcal{A} \hookrightarrow K(\mathcal{A}$) this becomes
> a distinguished triangle $A \to B \to C \xrightarrow{\delta} A[1]$ in
> $K(\mathcal{A})$ (respectively $ D(\mathcal{A})$) with $\delta$ given
> as the composition of the inverse (in
> $K(\mathcal{A})$ respectively $D(\mathcal{A})$) of the
> quasi-isomorphism $C(f) \to C $ and the natural
> morphism $C(f) \to A[1]$.

> Conversely, if $A \to B \to C \to A[1]$ is a distinguished
> triangle with objects $A,B, C \in \mathcal{A} $,
> then $ 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0 $ is a short exact
> sequence in $\mathcal{A}$.

The $K(\mathcal{A})$ is the homotopy category of complexes
whose objects are the objects of $\text{Kom}(\mathcal{A})$,
i.e. complexes in $\mathcal{A}$ and morphisms chain maps
modulo homotopy relation. $D(\mathcal{A})= Q_{is}^{-1}K(\mathcal{A})$
is the localization of $K(\mathcal{A})$ with respect to
quasi-isomorphims. It has same objects as $K(\mathcal{A})$, but
the construction of morphisms becomes a bit more involved, see
Remark 2.14. Roughly the morphims of $A,B \in D(\mathcal{A})$
are certain equivalence classes of "roofs"
$A \xleftarrow{s} B' \to B$ where $s: B' \to A $ is a quasi-isomorphism.

Questions:

1. I see how to show that a short exact sequence
   $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \to C \to 0$
   gives a distinguished triangle
   $A \to B \to C \xrightarrow{\delta} A[1]$ (with $\delta$
   as required) in $D(\mathcal{A})$ (!), but why this also
   holds in $K(\mathcal{A})$?
   In $D(\mathcal{A})$ the map $\delta$ can be constructed
   as $A \xleftarrow{q} C(f) \xrightarrow{\text{pr}_A} A[1]$
   where $q: C(f) \to C$ is canonically induced by $f$ and is quasi-isomorphism
   by assumption on exactness of the sequence, and
   $\text{pr}_A:C(f) \to A[1]$ is the canonical projection to the
   shifted factor.
2. Why the converse statement is true? Assume
   $A \to B \to C \to A[1]$ is distinguished, why is then
   $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \to C 
   \to 0$ exact? Just to clarify, if
   $A \to B \to C \to A[1]$ is distinguished in $K(\mathcal{A})$,
   then it follows easily via little diagram chase. Recall in $K(\mathcal{A})$ we regard $A,B,C$ as complexes with only nonzero entry in degree zero term, so homotopy relation not identifies "too much".
   But how to show it if
   $A \to B \to C \to A[1]$ is assumed to be distinguished
   in $D(\mathcal{A})$? There the morphisms are more complicated, so diagram chase arguments like in $K(\mathcal{A})$ not work anymore.